Lubuntu 24 04 installation on pc with ssd and hard disk : no dual-boot menu
I bought a second hand hp pc with about 60 Go on SSD storage and 1 To hard disk. It has windows on the SSD, so I thought I would put Lubuntu on the hard disk.
I got the latest long term support Lubuntu (mangled mantra or whatever - edit : Noble Numbat, 24.04.1) and I checked the hash sum. It was ok. So I rebooted from windows, telling it to boot from usb. It took a long time but eventually it booted and I had the choice between try Lubuntu or install Lubuntu. I chose install.
I selected the hard disk, using the entire hard disk. I didn't know whether grub would add a windows option at boot time, because windows was on the SSD. It never got that far.
The installation seemed to go as usual but at the end it said :
Installation failed 

Command <i>calamares-logs-helper /tmp/calamares-root-15j00610</i> finished with exit code 1. 

Cannot open '/var/log/casper.log' for reading : input/output error.

and some more stuff about copying calamares files. When I click "ok"  it goes back to Lubuntu, as if I had selected "Test Lubuntu".
At first I tried the normal install, then the small install (only Desktop stuff). The third time I thought I should maybe put it online so I did so, via wifi. Same result.
I'm considering trying to create an installation usb stick with the previous LTS Lubuntu, 22.04.5 (Jammy Jellyfish), I can always type "do-release-upgrade" later. But maybe this has nothing to do with it.
It's the first time I try an install on a pc which has both SSD and hard disk. Maybe the problem comes from that?
Now I'm back to windows, which still functions except it can no longer see the hard disk. That is as I expected. I would prefer to keep it for the rare occasions when I might need it, but I'll overwrite it if I have to.
EDIT : The report made by running "boot-repair" with the default options is below.
To bring back windows : 
change
/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/rem_bootmgfw.efi
into
/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi


boot-repair-4ppa2081                                              [20241022_1009]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================




Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sdb5,
using the following options:  sdb1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS entry (sdb1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-47-generic
The settings chosen by the user will reinstall the grub-efi of
sdb5,
using the following options:  sdb1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file


/boot/efi added in sdb5/fstab
/dev/sdb5/boot/efi not empty

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdb5/etc/default/grub

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of /dev/sdb5 ======================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.12-1ubuntu7
modprobe: FATAL: Module efivars not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-47-generic
modprobe efivars

efibootmgr -v (filtered) before grub install
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 20 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,3000,0005,2001,2002,2004,0003,0002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,1695ed28-bfe9-4fc4-b2c2-bb0e33413587,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,1695ed28-bfe9-4fc4-b2c2-bb0e33413587,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIubuntugrubx64.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000061000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0002* Internal Hard Drive - ST1000LM035-1RK172  BBS(HD,Internal Hard Drive - ST1000LM035-1RK172,0x500)feff05000000000000000000000001062d0052e602000005190052e6410052e6000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d887c9ae110002010c00d041030a0000000001010600020801010600000003120a000000000000007fff0400
Boot0003* Internal Hard Drive - SanDisk SD9SN8W-128G-1006   BBS(HD,Internal Hard Drive - SanDisk SD9SN8W-128G-1006,0x500)feff05000000000000000000000001062d0059e602000005190059e6410059e6000000120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000088ec9ae120002010c00d041030a0000000001010600020801010600000003120a000100000000007fff0400
Boot0005* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,1695ed28-bfe9-4fc4-b2c2-bb0e33413587,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC

uname -r
6.8.0-47-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/sdb1
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v (filtered) after grub install
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 20 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0000,3000,2001,2002,2004,0003,0002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,1695ed28-bfe9-4fc4-b2c2-bb0e33413587,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,1695ed28-bfe9-4fc4-b2c2-bb0e33413587,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIubuntugrubx64.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000061000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0002* Internal Hard Drive - ST1000LM035-1RK172  BBS(HD,Internal Hard Drive - ST1000LM035-1RK172,0x500)feff05000000000000000000000001062d0052e602000005190052e6410052e6000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d887c9ae110002010c00d041030a0000000001010600020801010600000003120a000000000000007fff0400
Boot0003* Internal Hard Drive - SanDisk SD9SN8W-128G-1006   BBS(HD,Internal Hard Drive - SanDisk SD9SN8W-128G-1006,0x500)feff05000000000000000000000001062d0059e602000005190059e6410059e6000000120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000088ec9ae120002010c00d041030a0000000001010600020801010600000003120a000100000000007fff0400
Boot0005* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,1695ed28-bfe9-4fc4-b2c2-bb0e33413587,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/lubuntu-grub-theme.cfg'
Found theme: /usr/share/grub/themes/lubuntu-grub-theme/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic
Found memtest86+ 64bit EFI image: /boot/memtest86+x64.efi
Found Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (22.04) on /dev/sda1
Found Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (24.04) on /dev/sda2
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sdb5/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS entry (sdb1/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
                       /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sdb4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:
    Boot files:

sdb5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub


================================ 4 OS detected =================================

OS#1 (linux):   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on sdb5
OS#2 (linux):   Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS on sda1
OS#3 (linux):   Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on sda2
OS#4 (windows):   Windows 10 or 11 on sdb3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Picasso/Raven 2 [Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series] from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic root=UUID=e473ae63-8a11-4c2d-bd34-b23b26bc9c0a ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/sdb5      ext4   59G  8.7G   47G  16% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F.13(15.13) from Insyde
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0005
Timeout: 20 seconds
BootOrder: 0005,0000,3000,2001,2002,2004,0003,0002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,1695ed28-bfe9-4fc4-b2c2-bb0e33413587,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0001* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,1695ed28-bfe9-4fc4-b2c2-bb0e33413587,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)57494e444f5753000100000088000000780000004200430044004f0042004a004500430054003d007b00390064006500610038003600320063002d0035006300640064002d0034006500370030002d0061006300630031002d006600330032006200330034003400640034003700390035007d00000061000100000010000000040000007fff0400
Boot0002* Internal Hard Drive - ST1000LM035-1RK172  BBS(HD,Internal Hard Drive - ST1000LM035-1RK172,0x500)feff05000000000000000000000001062d0052e602000005190052e6410052e6000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d887c9ae110002010c00d041030a0000000001010600020801010600000003120a000000000000007fff0400
Boot0003* Internal Hard Drive - SanDisk SD9SN8W-128G-1006   BBS(HD,Internal Hard Drive - SanDisk SD9SN8W-128G-1006,0x500)feff05000000000000000000000001062d0059e602000005190059e6410059e6000000120000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000088ec9ae120002010c00d041030a0000000001010600020801010600000003120a000100000000007fff0400
Boot0005* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,1695ed28-bfe9-4fc4-b2c2-bb0e33413587,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk    RC


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sdb : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb5    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sdb4    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
sdb3    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sdb1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   no-grubenv, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sda1    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   no-grubenv, update-grub,    end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb5    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sdb4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sdb3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ntfs
sdb1    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, vfat
sda2    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4
sda1    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot, ext4

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sdb5    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sdb
sdb4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb3    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sdb1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sdb
sda2    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda
sda1    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: E2203556-7D3B-43BA-827A-A667A7BEDB87
         Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1  977069282 1953520064 976450783 465.6G Linux filesystem
sda2     618496  977069280 976450785 465.6G EFI System
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sdb: 119.24 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk identifier: 9EDAE009-C871-4072-88DA-061A32150D06
         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
sdb1       2048    206847    204800  100M EFI System
sdb2     206848    239615     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
sdb3     239616 124617393 124377778 59.3G Microsoft basic data
sdb4  248995840 250066943   1071104  523M Windows recovery environment
sdb5  124617395 248995169 124377775 59.3G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1:;
2:317MB:500GB:500GB:ext4:lubuntu_2404:boot, esp;
1:500GB:1000GB:500GB:ext4:root:;
sdb:128GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA SanDisk SD9SN8W-:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp, no_automount;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres, no_automount;
3:123MB:63.8GB:63.7GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:63.8GB:127GB:63.7GB:ext4:root:;
4:127GB:128GB:548MB:ntfs::hidden, diag, no_automount;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

sda: 0.02MiB:302MiB:302MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
sda
├─sda1 ext4     940bd12b-0dc1-46ed-87fe-bfdb0eb9715a 0743ba8e-41a2-2348-a1b6-bd267db8e265       root
└─sda2 ext4     2004cf58-df38-4ee0-9743-de134566f377 0a31c475-0ebc-43de-ae7e-da3195c5c047       lubuntu_2404
sdb
├─sdb1 vfat     98FB-4A13                            1695ed28-bfe9-4fc4-b2c2-bb0e33413587       EFI system partition
├─sdb2                                               c060020c-f85c-4909-9707-34ddafa37d15       Microsoft reserved partition
├─sdb3 ntfs     E4DC0031DC000092                     e349bdfd-ec73-4acd-b521-94648fac4d18 SSD   Basic data partition
├─sdb4 ntfs     3CF02F0CF02ECC48                     d339b6c4-239c-4c12-9299-291012434792
└─sdb5 ext4     e473ae63-8a11-4c2d-bd34-b23b26bc9c0a c4d15a4d-60f5-b043-b259-8d25ca8ef7a1       root

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                427G   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2              425.9G   2% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sdb3               21.1G  64% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb3
/dev/sdb4               88.7M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sdb4
/dev/sdb5               46.5G  15% /
efivarfs                81.8K  46% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/sda1              ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda2              ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sdb3              fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb4              fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb5              ext4            rw,relatime,discard

========================== sda1/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=2004cf58-df38-4ee0-9743-de134566f377 /boot/efi      ext4    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=940bd12b-0dc1-46ed-87fe-bfdb0eb9715a /              ext4    defaults   0 1
/swapfile                                 swap           swap    defaults   0 0

======================= sda1/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 469.502778053 = 504.124769280  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 469.502778053 = 504.124769280  boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic                  1
 469.502778053 = 504.124769280  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 470.352887154 = 505.037566976  boot/initrd.img                                1
 470.352887154 = 505.037566976  boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic               1
 470.352887154 = 505.037566976  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sda1: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec 18  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec 18  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec 18  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec 18  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 May 17  2023 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom

========================== sda2/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=2004cf58-df38-4ee0-9743-de134566f377 /              ext4    defaults   0 1
/swapfile                                 swap           swap    defaults   0 0

======================= sda2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda2: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   4.411827087 = 4.737163264    boot/vmlinuz                                   1
   3.941654205 = 4.232318976    boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic                  1
   4.411827087 = 4.737163264    boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic                  1
   3.941654205 = 4.232318976    boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
   5.718132019 = 6.139797504    boot/initrd.img                                2
   4.046760559 = 4.345176064    boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-41-generic               1
   5.718132019 = 6.139797504    boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic               2
   4.046760559 = 4.345176064    boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sda2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Apr  5  2024 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr  4  2024 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr  4  2024 41_custom

===================== sdb1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid e473ae63-8a11-4c2d-bd34-b23b26bc9c0a root hd1,gpt5
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sdb5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   e473ae63-8a11-4c2d-bd34-b23b26bc9c0a
Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (22.04) (on sda1)   940bd12b-0dc1-46ed-87fe-bfdb0eb9715a
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (24.04) (on sda2)   2004cf58-df38-4ee0-9743-de134566f377
Windows Boot Manager (on sdb1)   osprober-efi-98FB-4A13
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sdb5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system>             <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=e473ae63-8a11-4c2d-bd34-b23b26bc9c0a /              ext4    defaults,discard 0 1
/swapfile                                 swap           swap    defaults   0 0
tmpfs                                     /tmp           tmpfs   defaults,noatime,mode=1777 0 0
UUID=98FB-4A13  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

======================= sdb5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`( . /etc/os-release; echo ${NAME:-Ubuntu} ) 2>/dev/null || echo Ubuntu`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

==================== sdb5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
  75.301396847 = 80.854259200   boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
  62.162694454 = 66.746684928   boot/vmlinuz                                   1
  65.865808010 = 70.722872832   boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic                  2
  62.162694454 = 66.746684928   boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-47-generic                  1
  65.865808010 = 70.722872832   boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
  76.000993252 = 81.605445120   boot/initrd.img                                1
  76.071313381 = 81.680950784   boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-40-generic               2
  76.000993252 = 81.605445120   boot/initrd.img-6.8.0-47-generic               1
  76.071313381 = 81.680950784   boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sdb5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18133 Apr  4  2024 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43202 Apr  4  2024 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14513 Apr  4  2024 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   786 Apr  4  2024 25_bli
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13120 Apr  4  2024 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1174 Apr  4  2024 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   722 Aug 21 20:39 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom



I installed lubuntu 22.04.5 side by side with Windows 10 on the SSD. Then I do-release-upgrade it to 24.04.1.. On the hard disk I have 2 installations of lubuntu, one of each version, which, AFAIK, are not accessible. The pc still boots into Windows, I have to repeatedly hit F9 at startup if I want to boot Lubuntu. Then I have the choice between "OS Boot Manager (UEFI) - Windows Boot Manager (SanDisk SD9 SN8W-128G-1006)" and "OS Boot Manager (UEFI) - ubuntu (SanDisk SD9 SN8W-128G-1006)". How can I get a proper boot menu, such as grub, to take control at startup?

Still not there. I think I found the guilty party : /boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Renaming "bootmgfw.efi" "rem_bootmgfw.efi" makes the computer boot with ubuntu or ubuntu recovery options. No option to boot into windows. At one point I see an empty black square where a menu should be. bootmgfw.efi is crypted, not a proper parameter file I could read and edit with "sudo nano bootmgfw.efi". Computers with SSD and hard disk have been around for a while, but tutorials like https://itsfoss.com/dual-boot-hdd-ssd/ tell me not to worry about  ‘Device for boot loader installation’.

Now I've got the option to boot into Windows showing on the menu, but selecting it doesn't function (it says it can't find bootmgfw.efi). But if I give back its proper name to that file, then I can't boot into Ubuntu without hitting F9. I'm going round in circles.
